# rails assert_difference without specific difference value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests, assert

I'm new to rails tests and I'm trying to understand the call to `assert_difference`. From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_difference), I deduce that the method requires a numerical value for the difference between the previous and the final value of the expression. What if I just want to assert that there is a difference, no matter how big it is? Maybe something like `assert_not (assert_no_difference ... )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you'll notice that the signature for the method is:

```
assert_difference(expression, difference = 1, message = nil, &block)
```

The `difference = 1` indicates that the method sets 1 as the default value for the difference argument if no value is provided.

The general idea behind this method is that there will be a specific change in the value of something that you want to verify in your test. If you want to just test that a value has changed you can use your own variables and asserts.

Maybe something like the following will suffice:

```
value = 0
new_value = some_function
assert_not_equal value, new_value
```

Best of luck!